# Wordpress multisite subdomain gives error 404

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, subdomain, multisite

wish everything is going well with you all.
I've recently set mu WP to WP multisite networking based on subdomain addressing.
I have created a wildcard subdomain on my server and set addressed it.
Changed the configurations on my wp-config.php file and also replaced the .htaccess contents as it must be.
how ever, when I add a subdomain, I can see that in My sites sections next to my main domain with 2 anchor links of: "visit site" and "dashboard".
But, when I want to go to the subdomain dashboard it gives me a 404 error.
I've already disabled all plugins and the problem still exists.
Really don't know how to get rid of this problem.
It would be really appreciated if anyone can help me in this...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sv2Om.png)